# AngularJS: ui-sref on panel & inner link

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

For example i have such code:

```
<div class="panel" ui-sref="product.details({id: someId})">
  <div class="panel-sub-link">
    some another event is here
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6qmvk6g9/)

[image]

is it possible somehow not to call parent ui-sref, when i click on sub-link element? this is just an abstractive example... With more details: for example i have a panel and a slider (with navigation arrows), when i click on arrows - i do not need to change my state. How can i do this?

Comment: no need to use sref if you're using slider :/

Comment: if it was an example, BTW you can define that state separately !

Comment: @MajidNayyeri panel should change state onClick! slider, sure, not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ui-sref` isn't the only option to navigate between states. We still have `$state.go` right?

In place of `ui-sref`, you can simply add `ng-click` referring to a function in controller performing `$state.go("product.details...")`. And, in your panel, where you don't want to visit state on-click, you can have `$event.stopPropogation`.

Something like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppController">
  <div class="panel" ng-click="navigate(someId)">
    <div class="panel-sub-link" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">
      some another event is here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And, `navigate` function in controller like this:

```
$scope.navigate = function(someId) {
  console.log("going to product details")
  $state.go("product.details", {
    id: someId
  })
}
```

That should do it!

[**working sample example**](http://jsfiddle.net/789Ks/371/)